# How to create onSubmit event in new Google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

In the new google form (since end-2015) , I can't find the "script Editor" button. Is is still available?

Answer (score 0):

Add-ons ( and I'm assuming script editor ) "coming soon" as mentioned in official support doc - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888?hl=en

if you switch back to the old Forms version by clicking the "exit" icon in lower left:

[image]

you can then insert your code and upgrade again if you want.